# Rails autoload module when application started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have module `Mymodule`,inside lib directory, within few methods inside

```
  module Mymodule

    def usefull_meth(a,b)
     a+b
    end

  end
```

i want to autoload it when my app started

i have inside my `application.rb`

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/*"]`

but i still need to include it like `include Mymodule`

i want to use my `usefull_meth(a,b)` inside `application helper` without inclusion

how i can achieve my goal? or i have done something wrong?

I simply want to have `usefull_meth` *anywhere* in my helpers,i do not need `Mymodule.usefull_meth` or smth else

Answer (score 0):

> but i still need to include it like include Mymodule

This is how Ruby works, it has nothing to do with Rails autoload.

In order to use some method globally, you should put it into global namespace. Just remove module definition and leave only method definition in that file(even though I don't understand why don't you put it into helper directly).

Comment: `don't understand why don't you put it into helper directly`, because it method based on other calculations inside module,if  can say so its final output

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what i wanted

inside `application.rb`

```
require  './lib/my_module'
include Mymodule
```

and now i have necessary methods with out `include Mymodule`